# Partial download in revisions

Tags: google-drive-api

Is possible to do a partial download in a specific revision?

In files there is no problem but in revisions the download operation retrieve all bytes instead of the range that I specified.

The URL is:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file_id}/revisions/{revision_id}?alt=media

And I set this header on each request

Range: bytes={init}-{end}.

Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed that with any revision file of any size, the method retrieve approximately 33Mb. I set 10mb at the "Range" header.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the v3 API and it is still broken as of 2020-10-28.

You can use range requests for revisions by using the v2 API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{file_id}?alt=media&revisionId={revision_id}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: I opened a bug report for this problem in the public Google Drive issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171904226

Comment: The issue mentioned above is fixed, so zou can now make range requests using the v3 API and get the expected response.